# jQuery UI dialog won't open in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
    }
});
```

I am trying to open this dialog just before an AJAX call. It works using Firefox, but with IE it doesn't open, unless I put an `alert`, just after I open the dialog. Can anyone tell me what the problem might be please? I am using the following code:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    //alert('test'); //if I put this alert, the dialog will open
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testing.txt",
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(returnText) {
            $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            $("#textarea").text(returnText);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `open` event completes asynchronously due to potential animations, therefore what is likely happening is that due to IE's slow JavaScript interpretation, the code to close the dialog in the `success` or `error` callbacks (which are also asynchronous) are executing close enough to the  `open` that you don't notice dialog ever being opened.  I'm going to guess that your AJAX call is completing very quickly.

One way around this it to put your AJAX call in a `setTimeout` block.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testing.txt",
            async: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(returnText) {
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                $("#textarea").text(returnText);
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            }
        });
    }, 1);
});
```

This will simply queue up the `$.ajax` call which will allow the `open` event to complete.  John Resig has a nice write up on why this sort of thing works here - http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!!
I also, have a GIF animation in my popup, but it doesn't work. Do you know what this problem might be please?

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't work.  Can you look at the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools or the Net tab in Firebug to see if the image is being requested and returned correctly?  It might be a problem of the image needing to be pre-fetched which you can do by calling `new Image('path/to/myImage.png');` somewhere early in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem is putting the "dialog.open" part in the mousedown event instead of click. That way you can still do stuff IE(8) doesn't like when you put it in a setTimeout, like downloading a file.